# In Kotlin, is it possible to use a variable to call a method or property?

Tags: variables, properties, kotlin, evaluation

Simply put, I have a variable that tells me which property I need to modify on an object, but cannot call that property AS the variable.

```
data class MyDataClass(var one: String, var two: Int)

fun doSomething() {
    myData = MyDataClass("first", 2)

    val propertyImInterestedIn = "one"

    myData.{propertyImInterestedIn} = "second" // How do I do this?

    assertEquals("second", myData.one)
}
```

Comment: Your example does not clearly tell what exactly you want to achieve, so I'm not sure I could answer correctly. Do you want to reference the property directly, or do you need to find it by its value?

Comment: Sorry, I noticed a typo. I have corrected it. I need to set the property named "one". But, at compile time, I do not know what the name of the property is. Granted, the example is contrived. In reality, `propertyImInterestedIn` would be calculated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either do it at compile time if You can directly reference the fields, or at runtime but you will lose compile-time safety:

```
// by referencing KProperty directly (compile-time safety, does not require kotlin-reflect.jar)
val myData = MyDataClass("first", 2)
val prop = myData::one
prop.set("second")

// by reflection (executed at runtime - not safe, requires kotlin-reflect.jar)
val myData2 = MyDataClass("first", 2)
val reflectProp = myData::class.memberProperties.find { it.name == "one" }
if(reflectProp is KMutableProperty<*>) {
    reflectProp.setter.call(myData2, "second")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Kotlin reflection API to do that, and [bound callable references](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-function-and-property-references-since-11) in particular:

```
val propertyImInterestedIn = myData::one
propertyImInterestedIn.set("second")
```

Note that you need to add [`kotlin-reflect`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect) as a dependency to your project.