# Kotlin data class - access property by variable to set it's value

Tags: reflection, kotlin, data-class

I have a Kotlin data class like this:

```
data class User(
    var id: Int,
    var name: String? = null,
    var email: String? = null,
    var age: Int? = null,
    var latitude: Float? = null,
    var longitude: Float? = null 
)
```

Then I create it's instance

```
var user = User(1)
```

Then I try this:

```
val field = "name"
var prop = User::class.memberProperties.find {it -> it.name == field}!!
prop.get(user)
```

And it works, but if I try to set value like this:

```
prop.setter.call(user, "Alex")
```

I get an error:

> Unresolved reference: setter

Neither it works like this:

```
prop.set(user, "Alex")
```

(This was based on solution provided here, but it isn't work for me: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715815/in-kotlin-is-it-possible-to-use-a-variable-to-call-a-method-or-property) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memberProperties` returns a `Collection<KProperty1<T, *>>`, but you need [`KMutableProperty1`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-mutable-property/index.html). So

```
if (prop is KMutableProperty1) {
    (prop as KMutableProperty1<T, Any>).set(user, "Alex")
} else { 
    // what do you want to do if the property is immutable?
}
```

The cast is needed because the smart cast would only give you a `KMutableProperty1<T, *>` and you couldn't call `set` anyway because the compiler doesn't know what type to accept as its second parameter.

Comment: this solution is not working as I am facing exception `kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KProperty1Impl cannot be cast to kotlin.reflect.KMutableProperty1`

Comment: Are you sure your property is actually mutable? For a mutable property you should see [`KMutableProperty1Impl`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/fbb0d6d805894dc0915faee7dbf28d8e1e581efd/core/reflection.jvm/src/kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/KProperty1Impl.kt#L48) which can be cast to `KMutableProperty1`.

Answer (score 0):

when you got the instance of your object needed, you simply do -> user.name = "toto"

Comment: It is OK if I want to set exactly "name" property to "toto". In my case I have an object with more than 20 properties and a hash map with properties' names and values to change in this object. I can iterate over hash map to get (key, value) pairs, but I can't call data class instance property simply by "user[key]"

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java-style reflection if you're targeting the JVM platform.
To set the "name" property of the user instance of the class User to "Alex",

```
val field = "name"
user.javaClass
    .getMethod("set${field.capitalize()}", String::class.java)
    .invoke(user, "Alex")
```

And to get the "name" property,

```
val userName = user.javaClass
    .getMethod("get${field.capitalize()}")
    .invoke(user) as String
```